# Reload My Location button when permission is granted

Tags: google-maps, flutter

## Background

I am using the google_maps_flutter package to show a map with markers corresponding to houses. To avoid overloading devices, I only load houses near the location the user is looking at. To make this easier, I request the user's location and provide that to Google Maps in order to show a My Location button.

## The Problem

If location access has already been granted, it works as intended. Whoever if the map is already loaded, the My Location button does not show up.

Currently, if location permission is granted while the map is on-screen, I simply move the camera over to their location. This is an OK workaround, but I'd rather let the user decide where to look.

How can I load in the button when permission is granted while the map is already loaded?

## Tried

1. I have tried just setting state.
2. Manually marking the map as dirty.
3. Forcing the map to reload options using a test method.

I've checked every available method I had access to, so at this point I doubt there is any other option. If this is the case I will report it as a bug.

## My Code

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Load markers when permission is granted.
    location.hasPermission().then((currPerm) async {
      if (!currPerm) {
        bool newPerm = await location.requestPermission();
        if (newPerm) {
          LocationData data = await location.getLocation();
          (await mapController.future).moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude)));
        }
      }
    });

    GoogleMap map = GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: INIT_POS,
        zoom: 11.5,
      ),
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      trafficEnabled: true,
      markers: markers,
      onMapCreated: (newController) => mapController.complete(newController),
      onCameraIdle: () async {
        // Load markers when the camera stops moving.
        LatLngBounds bounds = await (await mapController.future).getVisibleRegion();
        loadMarkers(
          LatLng(
            (bounds.northeast.latitude + bounds.southwest.latitude)/2,
            (bounds.northeast.longitude + bounds.southwest.longitude)/2
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    return map;
  }
```

Comment: Without code, no one can answer you :'(

Please provide the code that you are talking about.

Comment: There you go. I hope that is enough. I can definitely add additional context if needed.

Comment: I think this is in fact a bug. There is no reason for it not work.

Comment: Why don't you trigger a moveCamera regardless if it is the first time the user grants permission?

Comment: Maybe that is what renders the button that you want

Comment: I already do. It moves the camera but does not add the button.

Answer (score 7):

As of `google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.23+1`, I solved it by assigning a variable to `myLocationEnabled`, and changing its value once I got the location permission. If you hardcode `true`, it just won't work.

```dart
GoogleMap map = GoogleMap(
      myLocationEnabled: _isLocationGranted,
      ...
```

So, `_isLocationGranted` is initially `false`. When I get location permission, I set it to `true` and rebuild the widget (by calling `setState()`, triggering `BlocBuilder()`, or whatever method you use).

The other related parameter, `myLocationButtonEnabled: true`, doesn't seem to need this handling.

Comment: I've got the same problem can you give an example of how you did?